# protobuf symbol lookup error

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am generating a library called libfoo.so which makes use of protobuf and it is being generated successfully. But when I am using libfoo.so for dynamic linking, it is giving the below symbol lookup error.

> Symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8internal12kEmptyStringB5cxx11E with protobuf-2.5.1 version

and

> Symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8internal13empty_string_B5cxx11E with protbuf-2.6.1 version

I have tried with different versions of protobuf, but still the issues persists, can anyone help me in this regards.

Thanks in advance.
Jai

Comment: Try passing `-lprotobuf` to clang/gcc or whatever the equivalent for VS is.

Comment: Thanks for the input nwp, I have used the same by providing absolute path to the libprotobuf.so.0 as LDFLAG and it resolved the issue.

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Some update will change the file to `protobuf.so.1` and then your build breaks. In order to prevent that the system should have a symbolic link from `protobuf.so` to `protobuf.so.0`. Use that instead.